# How to dynamically add an element to HTML5 SVG?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, createelement

I have read a few questions similar to this, but I can't get my code working properly. I want to add a SVG element when a the user click on the SVG-area.

Here is my HTML5 with SVG, it renders correctly:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="svgdraw.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <svg id="canvas" width="500" height="500">
    <circle cx="80" cy="80" r="50" fill="blue"/>
    </svg>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the JavaScript that is executed on a click event:

```
    var svgDocument = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
    var shape = svgDocument.createElementNS(svgns,"circle");
    shape.setAttributeNS(null, "cx", 25);
    shape.setAttributeNS(null, "cy", 25);
    shape.setAttributeNS(null, "r", 20);
    shape.setAttributeNS(null, "fill", "green");
    document.getElementById('canvas').appendChild(shape);
```

In Google Chrome I get an error message that `createElementNS` doesn't exist. But I can't get it working if I remove all `NS` and `null` either. What is the correct way to do this? Is is different for different browsers?

Comment: When I tried to replicate your problem I encountered that *svgDocument* was undefined. Any idea why thats happening?

Comment: I though html5 didn't required namespace anymore ?!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I know `createElementNS()` is part of the `document`-variable, try:

```
var shape = document.createElementNS(svgns,"circle");
```

Comment: The createElementNS is an function requires two values, the namespace and an object name. The first is formatted like an URL, the latter can be anything. @Jonas has the URL-type value stored in svgns (SVG Namespace), see the question, so I just re-use that variable.